# Bing removed page from index after switching from WordPress to Next,js

Tags: wordpress, bing, bing-webmaster-tools, next.js

My site had been ranking well (position ~4 page 1) on Bing, but after switching from WordPress to Next.js, Bing Webmaster Tools says it can't be indexed.

Any idea what could be wrong? The webpage is way faster, has much more content, and better UX.

> The inspected URL is known to Bing but has some issues which are preventing indexation. We recommend you to follow Bing Webmaster Guidelines to increase your chances of indexation.

Bing Live URL inspector says:

> URL can be indexed by Bing
> It can appear on Bing Search results given it passes quality checks and gets indexed by Bing

Here are the screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Have you added the alt attribute ?